# Iterate through collection, perform action on each item and return as List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there any way to do it with java 8 Stream API?

I need to transform each item of collection to other type (dto mapping) and return all set as a list...

Something like

```
Collection<OriginObject> from = response.getContent();
DtoMapper dto = new DtoMapper();    
List<DestObject> to = from.stream().forEach(item -> dto.map(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());

public class DtoMapper {
    public DestObject map (OriginObject object) {
        return //conversion;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Update #1: the only stream object is `response.getContent()`

Comment: `dto.stream().flatMap(r -> r.getContent().stream()).map(...).collect(...);`?

Comment: Do you want to mutate the objects in the list, or do you want to create a new list of modified objects?

Comment: @AlexisC. `dto` is not stream object.. See question's update

Comment: What's the type of response.getContent()?

Comment: @aioobe Collection<SomeObject> where SomeObject is Resource<Object>

Comment: Got it. See if my answer makes sense... Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what you want your code to do.  Do you have an iterative version that compiles?

Comment: `List<DestObject> to = from.stream().map(item -> dto.map(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());` should compile without problems....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after the following:

```
List<SomeObject> result = response.getContent()
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(dto::map)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

// do something with result if you need.
```

Note that `forEach` is a terminal operation. You should use it if you want to do something with each object (such as print it). If you want to continue the chain of calls, perhaps further filtering, or collecting into a list, you should use `map`.

Comment: Already tried it.. The main problem is that `collect`  can not transform the original object's list into new one.. And gives me a compile error

Comment: Could you explain "transform the original objects list into a new one"? In what way does the code I wrote differ from your desired result?

Comment: `dto::map` transforms an original object into new one and collect just can't convert the whole collection of objects of new types

Comment: You said you wanted a new list rather than modifying the objects in the original list. Could you clarify what you mean by "convert the whole collection of objects of new types"?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you right.. dto::map maps the incoming object into outcoming.. and once I try your code - compiler can't convert to list of origin objects (before `map`) to list of mapped objects (after `map`)

Comment: You're not being very clear. So far you have mentioned incoming objects, outcoming objects, `SomeObject`, `DestObject` and `OriginObject`. The code I suggested takes `Collection<SomeObject>`, maps each such object to a `DestObject`, and returns the result as a `List<DestObject>`. If this is not what you're after, please clarify.